# Merge two tables and remove duplicates using join

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to join two tables but I am getting duplicate entries. below is my query.

table1

| col_id | col_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 2345 |
| 2 | 2654 |
| 3 | 4654 |
| 3 | 4054 |

table2

| col_id | col_status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

I am looking for result like

| col_id | col_status | col_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 2 | 2345 |
| 3 | 1 | 4654 |

I tried with distinct and join but I am getting duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `GROUP BY` clause along with the aggregate function `MAX()` to remove the duplicates from your query.
For example:

```
SELECT table1.col_id, table2.col_status, MAX(table1.col_name) AS col_name
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.col_id = table2.col_id
GROUP BY table1.col_id, table2.col_status;
```